# Loading XML with XDocument when xsi:nil

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to read this XML document with XDocument in c sharp.

```
  <Instrument_Root>
    <Instrument_ID>123</Instrument_ID>
    <Deal_number xsi:nil="true"/>
  </Instrument_Root>
```

I use the below code to read the XML doc:

```
   XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
```

I receive an error message because of the xsi:nil

Error merssage:An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll 'xsi' not declared.

Is there a way to treat xsi as NULL?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The namespace prefix `xsi` has to be declared somewhere for the document to be qualified as XML, for example :

```
<Instrument_Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Instrument_ID>123</Instrument_ID>
    <Deal_number xsi:nil="true"/>
</Instrument_Root>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the XML files to look like this:

```
<Instrument_Root  xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
    <Instrument_ID>123</Instrument_ID>
    <Deal_number xsi:nil="true"/>
</Instrument_Root>
```

[screencapture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yNs2.png)

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks